# Software to create bitmaps for GUI toolbar buttons

Tags: windows, gratis, images, gui, image-editor

Can anyone recommend software that facilitates the creation of bitmaps for GUI (Graphical User Interface) toolbar buttons?

**Requirements:**

1. Facilitates creating multiple states for a button, including enabled and disabled
2. Facilitates creating multiple sizes of the same image (eg. 16x16, 32x32, 48x48)
3. Supports alpha (transparent) pixels
4. Freeware (gratis)
5. Runs in Windows

**Preferences (not required):**

1. Supports gradients
2. Supports geometrics (eg. rectangles, ovals, triangles)
3. Facilitates generating shadows of objects in the images
4. Portable software
5. Currently maintained (not abandonware)
6. Open-source

Answer (score 2):

[Gimp](http://gimp.org):

Requirements:

1. Facilitates creating multiple states for a button, including enabled and disabled - *Has a "New Simple Beveled button" file entry, if you can come up with a simple rule for disabled state then you can script it*.
2. Facilitates creating multiple sizes of the same image (eg. 16x16, 32x32, 48x48) - *I would recommend always creating your biggest resolution first and down scaling to the others - you can even add a script to generate all the sizes and save them*
3. Supports alpha (transparent) pixels *Yes - depending on the file format selected*
4. Freeware (gratis) - *Free and Open Source*
5. Runs in Windows (any version) - *Yes you may need an older version to run on Win3.1 don't think it will run on Win2 but not much did - also runs on Linux/OSX/more*

Preferences (not required):

1. Supports gradients *Yes*
2. Supports geometrics (eg. rectangles, ovals, triangles) *Not directly did I mention scripting in Script-Fu or Python*
3. Facilitates generating shadows of objects in the images *Yes*
4. Portable software *Yes e.g.: from [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable)*
5. Currently maintained (not abandonware) *Very Actively*
6. Open-source *Yes*

Comment: Thanks Steve!  Is it overkill for the task?  (Also, when I wrote "any version" for Windows, my words clearly had multiple meanings... I meant as long as it runs on any version of Windows, not that it has to run on EVERY version of Windows... lol.)